# Every sequence in a compact set $E$ has at least one accumulation point

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Proof by contradiction. Say there is no accumulation point, therefore

$$\bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\Big(\overline{\bigcup_{n \geq k}\{x_n\} }\Big) = \emptyset$$

This is equivalent to
$$E = E \ \setminus \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\Big(\overline{\bigcup_{n \geq k}\{x_n\} }\Big)$$

Why is this equal to 
$$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\Big(E \setminus \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq k}\{x_n\} }\Big)?$$

Comment: The statement is not true. Consider $E=\mathbb R$ and $x_n = n$.

Comment: I've made an error in the title. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not about topology, but a result from general set theory. It all boils down to:

$$A\setminus\bigcap B_j = \bigcup A\setminus B_j$$

Which actually is a variant of the De Morgan law.

Answer (score 1):

$E \ \setminus \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\Big(\overline{\bigcup_{n \geq k}\{x_n\} }\Big)=\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\Big(E \setminus \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq k}\{x_n\} }\Big)$ is true by one of DeMorgan's Laws:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra